# Loading csv files in tensorflow -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tensorflow for a text classifier code. The tutorial I am going through is using the imdb dataset from Kaggle, and the code for loading it is :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
data = keras.datasets.imdb
(train_x,train_y),(test_x,test_y) = data.load_data()
```

Now, I have my own CSV file which I want to use as my dataset, how do I load that? 
Equivalent of something like this:

```
data='mydata.csv'
(train_x,train_y),(test_x,test_y) = data.load_data()
```

The dataset contains 2 columns (review,response). The 'mydata.csv' is also of an identical format, containing 2 columns and plain text data in both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("mydata.csv",delim_whitespace=True,header=None)
col_name=['review','response']
df.columns=col_name
```

Do upvote if liked!